# Raster Spatial Join of Two Datasets with Different Grid Cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst

I have two raster datasets with different resolution rates, dataset A is land use data with smaller grids, while dataset B is crop output per unit data with much larger grids.

I would like to join the two datasets, say, put the output data of each grid from B to every grid of A, which means each smaller grid of A would be added a new value called "crop output per unit". some grids of A are within B's grids, so I would like to simply add value of grids from B to the smaller A grids, some grids from A are on the border of two grids from B, maybe I can use the mean of the value from the two grids.

I am not sure whether GIS can realize it.

Comment: Try zonal statistics.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to resample one of your rasters so that they have the same size and aligned cells. [Resample](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/resample.htm) is probably the best option, but [Altering the resolution of a raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/altering-the-resolution.htm) gives some additional tool options. [Cell size and resampling in analysis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/performing-analysis/cell-size-and-resampling-in-analysis.htm) discusses in more detail the different methods that can be used to calculate the new values when resampling.

One thing to remain aware of in all of this is that resampling will change your data. If you apply the value of the larger raster (B) to all of the smaller cells in the the other raster (A) you are assuming B has homogeneous values across all it's cells. This may or may not be true, and may or may not negatively impact the results of your analysis.